# 400 Bad Request using mean stack

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, http, mean-stack

on my application, i can register (name, email, role) and login. when i log in my account i can update my role. But when i want to save my change after the click button onSave(), i have

```
`400 Bad Request` `ID Unknown:null`.
```

I'm on nodeJs express mongoodb and angular 14.

user.controller.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');
const { rest } = require('lodash');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
// updated crud code



ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; //catch collection Id
// end updated crud code



module.exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
//console.log('inside register function');
var user = new User();
user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.password = req.body.password;
user.role = req.body.role;
user.followers = req.body.followers;
user.following = req.body.following;
user.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err)
        res.send(doc);
    else {
        if (err.code = 1100)
            res.status(422).send(['L\'adresse email existe déja.']);
            else
                return next(err);
    } 

});
}

module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
//call for passport authentication
passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    //error from passport middleware
    if (err) return res.status(404).json(err);
    //registered user
    else if(user) return res.status(200).json({ "token" : user.generateJwt() });
    //unknow user or wrong password
    else return res.status(401).json(info);
 })(req,res);
}

module.exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) => {
User.findOne({ _id: req._id },
    (err, user) => {
        if (!user)
        return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'User record not found'});
        else
        return res.status(200).json({ status: true, user: _.pick(user,['fullName',  

'email', 'role', 'friends','followers','following']) });
    })
}

module.exports.getAllUser = async (req, res) => {
const users = await User.find().select('-password');
res.status(200).json(users);
};

module.exports.userInfo = (req, res) => {
if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

User.findById(req.params.id, (err,docs) => {
if(!err) res.send(docs);
else console.log('ID unknown ; ' . err);
}) .select('-password');

};

module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

try {
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: req.params.id},
  {
    $set: {
      role : req.body.role
    },
  },
  { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true},
)
  .then((docs) => res.send(docs))
  .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({ message: err }));

} catch (err){
return res.status(500).json({ message: err});
}
}

module.exports.deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

try {
await User.remove({_id: req.params.id}).exec();
res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully deleted. "});
 } catch (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
}

module.exports.follow = async (req, res) => {
/* if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id) || !ObjectId.isValid(req.params.idToFollow))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id) */

try {
// add to the follower list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id, // id wanted to being followed
  { $addToSet: { following: req.body.idToFollow } }, // id being followed
  { new : true, upsert: true },
  
);
// add to following list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.idToFollow,
  { $addToSet: { followers: req.params.id}},
  { new: true, upsert: true },
 )
   return res.status(201).json(docs);

  }catch (err) {
 return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
 }
};

 module.exports.unfollow = async (req, res) => {
/*  if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id) || !ObjectId.isValid(req.params.idToFollow))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id) */

try {
// add to the follower list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id, // id wanted to being followed
  { $pull: { following: req.body.idToUnFollow } }, // id being followed
  { new : true, upsert: true },
  
);
// add to following list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.idToUnFollow,
  { $pull: { followers: req.params.id}},
  { new: true, upsert: true },
)
return res.status(201).json(docs);

}catch (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
};
```

index.router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ctrlUser = require('../controllers/user.controller');

const jwtHelper = require('../config/jwtHelper');

//auth
router.post('/register', ctrlUser.register,);
router.post('/authenticate',ctrlUser.authenticate);


// user display 
router.get('/userProfile',jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, ctrlUser.userProfile);
router.get('/list', ctrlUser.getAllUser);
router.get('/user/:id', ctrlUser.userInfo);
router.put("/user/:id",ctrlUser.updateUser);
router.delete("/user/:id",ctrlUser.deleteUser);

//follow
 router.patch('/user/follow/:id', ctrlUser.follow);
router.patch('/user/unfollow/:id', ctrlUser.unfollow);



module.exports = router;
```

config.json

```
{
"development": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/PangolinDB",
    "JWT_SECRET": "LSDKFLSFQL.DFQSL.FSL",
    "JWT_EXP": "10m"
},
"production": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://xxxxx/DB_Name",
    "JWT_SECRET": "LSDKFLSFQL.DFQSL.FSL",
    "JWT_EXP": "2m"
}
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
};
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Observable, ObservableInput, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
selectedUser: User = {
id:'',
fullName: '',
email: '',
password: '',
role:'',
friends:'',
followers:'',
following:'',
};

noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True'}) };
errorMgmt: (err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<any>;
HttpHeaders: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

//httpMethods

//user form

//register ()
postUser(user: User){
return this.http.post( environment.apiBaseUrl+'/register',user,this.noAuthHeader);
}
//login ()
login(authCredentials: any){
  return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/authenticate', authCredentials,       

this.noAuthHeader);
}

//user profile
//user infos
getUserProfile(){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/userProfile');
} // need jwt in header

getOne(){
  const token = this.getToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization ':'bearer'+ token});
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl+'/userProfile',{headers});
}

updateUser(_id: any, value: any){
  return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseUrl + `/user/${_id}`, value);
  
}

edit(_id: any, data: any){
  return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseUrl + `/user/${_id}`, data);
  
}

//get all users
getAllUsers(){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/list');
}

//Helper Methods

setToken(token: string) {

  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}

getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

deleteToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
}

 getUserPayload(){
  var token = this.getToken();
  if (token) {
    var getUserPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
    return JSON.parse(getUserPayload);
  }
  else
  return null;
}

isLoggedIn() {
  var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
  if (userPayload)
    return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
  else
    return false;
}

// Error
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
let errorMessage = '';
if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Handle client error
  errorMessage = error.error.message;
} else {
  // Handle server error
  errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
}
console.log(errorMessage);
return throwError(() => {
  errorMessage;
});
}



}
```

edit.component.ts

```
import { UserService } from './../shared/user.service';
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validator, Validators, SelectControlValueAccessor,     

FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit',
templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
 })



export class EditComponent implements OnInit {


updateForm: FormGroup;
id:any;
role: string;

constructor(

public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
private router: Router,
private ngZone: NgZone,
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private UserService: UserService
) { 
this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.UserService.getOne().subscribe(res=>{
  this.updateForm.patchValue({
   
    role: res['role']
  });
});
this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  
  role:[''],
})

}
ngOnInit(): void {}
onUpdate(): any{
 
this.UserService.updateUser(this.id, this.updateForm.value).subscribe(()=>{
  console.log('mise à jouer effectuée avec succès')
  this.ngZone.run(()=> this.router.navigateByUrl('/userprofile'))
},(err)=> {
  console.log(err);
});
}

 } 




<div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
<div class="col-md-4">
<form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">
  <h2>Edit Role</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">Role</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="role" id="role">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" >Enregistrer</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" [routerLink]="['/userprofile']"    

type="submit">Retour</button>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>


<p>edit works!</p>
```

auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from  

"@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { UserService } from "../shared/user.service";

@Injectable()

 //recuperation de token
 export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 constructor(private userService : UserService,private router : Router){}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    if (req.headers.get('noauth'))
        return next.handle(req.clone());
    else {
        const clonedreq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " +   

  this.userService.getToken())
        });
        return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
            tap(
                event => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.error.auth == false) {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                    }
                })
        );
    }
   }
 }
```

After hours of searh i'm still blocked.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please create a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. Do you have any sort of logs available?

Comment: Note that this `if (err.code = 1100)` is not correct as `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.  It should be `if (err.code === 1100)`.

Comment: on my console log i have : `Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/null", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/user/null: 400 Bad Request", error: "ID unknown :null" }`